# Running WCF 3.5 app under .NET 4.0 website

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

I have a website that is hosted on IIS6 and set to use .NET 4.0, but I still have a WCF service on the site that is using 3.5.  When i browse my svc file, i get the error:

```
unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'
```

and it point to the websites root web.config.  I have tried this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759047.aspx) and still get the same error.  My site is using a different app pool than my WCF service, and is configured to use 4.0 in the ASP.NET tab of properties.  I have also checked and made sure that my WCF service is using 3.5(2.0) in its ASP.NET properties tab.

Answer (score 0):

IIS6 does not do mixed framework versions well. If you can switch to iis7 or bring both projects to the same .net version that will remedy the problem

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you run your WCF under 4.0? Most stuff should be compatible.